# I can't get value from application.properties in spring boot in any way

Tags: spring, multithreading, spring-boot, threadpool, application.properties

I've tried using ways.

```
@Value("${app.host})
```

```
@AutoWired
Environment environment
```

I can get value from the ***application.properties*** in other files, but when I try to get it from thread task where I've implemented Callable Interface, I'm getting value null.

Here my ***application.properties***

```
app.host = "xyz.com"
```

***Service***

```
ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<FTPClient> result = executorService.submit(new FtpConnector());
```

***FtpConnector.java***

```
import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

@Service
@PropertySource("classpath:application.properties")
public class FtpConnector implements Callable<FTPClient>{

    FTPClient ftpClient = new FTPClient();
    Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(FtpConnector.class);

    @Autowired
    FtpClient client;

    @Value("${app.host}")
    private String host;

    @Override
    public FTPClient call() throws Exception {
        logger.info("Host from connecter {}",host);
}
```

***output***

```
2022-03-02 20:44:03.831  INFO 15135 --- [ool-13-thread-1] t.a.tech.ftpnew.service.FtpConnector     : Host from connecter null
```

***Does anyone have any idea or solution to get values of application.properties in thread. ?***

Comment: Are you creating your own instance of FtpConnector or do you leave spring creating them for you? Can we see the code using the FtpConnector?

Comment: yes,I've added the code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you use `new FtpConnector()` it will not do any dependency injection thus `FtpClient` and `host` will not be injected. Do the following;

```
@Autowired
private FtpConnector ftpConnector;

ExecutorService executorService = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
Future<FTPClient> result = executorService.submit(ftpConnector);
```

Comment: yes, you are right but I'm having other issues that ftpconnector object passes as null in another file where I'm ```@Autowired``` it.